# Android AlarmManager setExact() is not exact

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I need to plan sheduled task every 10 minutes.

As in Lollipop and higher version `setRepeating()` is inexact, I use `setExact()` and (on alarm firing) I set new exact alarm in 10 minutes.

```
private void setAlarm(long triggerTime, PendingIntent pendingIntent) {
        int ALARM_TYPE = AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            alarmManager.setExact(ALARM_TYPE, triggerTime, pendingIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.set(ALARM_TYPE, triggerTime, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
```

`triggerTime` is calculated `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 600_000;`

When alarm fires, firstly I plan new one, only after that I run my sheduled task.

```
setAlarm();
mySheduledTask;
```

I do have `WAKE_LOCK` permission in my manifest.

When I test this on Android 4 - it works perfect (deviation might be 12-15 **milliseconds**).

But when I run app on Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 Pro (5.1.1) - deviation can be up to **15 seconds!**

For example, I see in my log file: first run was at 1467119934477 (of RTC time), second - at 1467120541683. Difference is **607_206** milliseconds, not **600_000**, as it was planned!

**What am I missing?** What is a way to simulate behaviour of system alarm (it's the most close usecase that can describe my tack)?

**PS.** I use IntentService for `PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, myIntent, 0);`

Answer (score 41):

The OS chooses how the alarms will work, with consideration of the time you've specified. Because of that, when the phone gets into a 'semi-sleep' mode, it won't necessary use the resource at the time you wish it to. Basically, it waits for 'windows' that the OS opens for it, and only then the alarm you want to run will run, that's why you're experiencing time gaps.

This was introduced on Marshmallow OS and will continue on Nougat OS as well, as part of Google trying to improve the device's battery.

Here's the thing, you have 2 options:

1. Accept the time delays (but maybe consider using [`JobScheduler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) which is more recommended and will save you battery).
2. Use [`setExactAndAllowWhileIdle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) which might cause you battery issues (use this carefully, too many alarms will be bad for your battery).
   This method isn't repeating, so you have to declare the next job to be run at the service which the pendingIntent opens.

If you choose option 2, here's the start:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
int ALARM_TYPE = AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(ALARM_TYPE, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    am.setExact(ALARM_TYPE, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
else
    am.set(ALARM_TYPE, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Good point, thanks. But the problem is on Lollipop, not on Marshmellow. Also, how system alarm is working (it works good, at the time it was planned)?

Comment: @Dus the third case is not exact because apps having targetSdkVersion 19 or later will treat set as inexact on devices having 18 and earlier. So, how to get exact alarm on pre-Kitkat devices with targetSdkVersion 25?

Comment: In second `if` Lollipop should be substituted with Kitkat.

Comment: Oh, I need to show sort of message to the user: "Sorry you haven't heard an alarm and did not get up on time, because exact alarm triggering will cause battery issues".

Comment: Recommending JobScheduler for an alarm clock app? Why?

Comment: This solution does not work for Lolipop (which the question was about). Lollipop is version API version 22, setExactAndAllowWhileIdle is API 23

Comment: I'm using `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` (on API level 28) but I do get inexact times. Strangely enough, most often these seem to be rounded to minutes: I set 5 min intervals, but I get 6, 10 or even 30, while very rarely "random" values. Anyone knows why this strange behaviour?

Comment: . Mr google, when I say exact I really mean EXACT, what's really the point of calling setExact... if it's not exact. Damn it.

Answer (score 11):

You can call the method from support.v4:

```
AlarmManagerCompat.setExact(...);
```

The internal implementation contains checks by sdk version.

Answer (score 8):

Probably a possible workaround could be something like this:
you schedule the Alarm about 1 minute before the expected time, than you use a Handler.postDelayed to cover the remaining time.

Here you can find an example of this kind of implementation.
The activity just set-up the first alarm:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int WAIT_TIME = 60*1000; //1 minute
    public static int DELAY_TIME = 10*60*1000; // delay between iterations: 10min
    public static String UPDATE_TIME_KEY = "update_time_key";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setAlarm(this,(new Date().getTime())+DELAY_TIME);
    }

    public static void setAlarm(Context context, long delay) {

        long fireDelay = delay-WAIT_TIME;
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putLong(UPDATE_TIME_KEY,delay).apply();

        Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, UpdateReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, startIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int ALARM_TYPE = AlarmManager.RTC;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            alarmManager.setExact(ALARM_TYPE, fireDelay, pendingIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.set(ALARM_TYPE, fireDelay, pendingIntent);
        }
    }

}
```

than the receiver continues the loop:

```
public class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("RECEIVED","RECEIVED");
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        long fireTime = sharedPreferences.getLong(MainActivity.UPDATE_TIME_KEY, (new Date()).getTime());

        long fireDelay  =(fireTime-(new Date().getTime())>0)?fireTime-(new Date().getTime()):0;

        (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.e("RECEIVED","PERFORMED");
                MainActivity.setAlarm(context,(new Date()).getTime()+MainActivity.DELAY_TIME);
            }
        },fireDelay);

    }

}
```

I hope it helped.

Comment: Interesting solution, upvoted it. But it's quite hacky, will use it only as a last resort. Thanks!

Comment: It's an interesting approach but what if your initial alarm doesn't fire ?

Answer (score 7):

To answer the question on the system alarm...

Android's stock Alarm Clock/Desk Clock app uses a combination of **setAlarmClock** and **setExactAndAllowWhileIdle**.

The following code is used to update notifications:

```
final PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, 
    AlarmStateManager.createIndicatorIntent(context), flags);
final AlarmClockInfo info = new AlarmClockInfo(alarmTime, viewIntent);

alarmManager.setAlarmClock(info, operation);
```

While at the same time the following code is used to schedule the actual alarm:

```
if (Utils.isMOrLater()) {
    // Ensure the alarm fires even if the device is dozing.
    alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, pendingIntent);
} else {
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
}
```

The Pending intent set in **setExactAndAllowWhileIdle** triggers the alarm while **setAlarmClock's** intent is then simply ignored.

[Android Googlesource](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/master/src/com/android/deskclock/alarms/AlarmStateManager.java)

Comment: Welcome to the world of Android, the world where even Google developers have to hack their way through.

Comment: I don't see the first part. Where is it exactly?

Comment: @androiddeveloper https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/master/src/com/android/deskclock/alarms/AlarmStateManager.java#235

Comment: But how do you see that the second is called after the other? They are in different functions, and I don't see them being called on after another.

Comment: @androiddeveloper the code isn't easy to follow, but it all starts with `registerInstance()` which sets the alarm state (which eventually calls the second bit of code) and updates notifications (the first bit of code).

Comment: Did it work for you though? I've noticed that in some cases, either it doesn't get triggered, or that I don't wait enough to see it. Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60079472/878126

Comment: @androiddeveloper it did work at the time I posted this answer, but I haven't tested it with the latest Android version.

Comment: Can you please try now? You can do it on emulator. It also has the same issue

Answer (score 2):

From android documentation of [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

> Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.

Also while using setExact() :

> The alarm will be delivered **as nearly as possible** to the requested trigger time.

So its still not guaranteed that setExact will be Exact.

Comment: I did read the documentation. Ok, then how does alarm on device works? It works good, without any deviations.

Answer (score 2):

You can try use [`AlarmManager.setAlarmClock`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) maybe it can help you.

Another thing you need to check which type of BroadcastReceiver you are using, it will be better to use [`WakefulBroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html)

Btw you need to change logic for work with Alarm Manager for support Android M, you can you something like this:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        setExact(...);
    } else {
        set(...);
    }
} else {
    setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(...);
}
```

Comment: Its written that setAlarmClock is like setExact, so I don't think, that switching will help much. About WakefulBroadcastReceiver - it's interesting, will try it, for now I'm using service.

Comment: WakefulBroadcastReceiver is deprecated now.