# How to give background notifications in android on exacly each hour everyday(eg.7:00am,8:00am,9:00am)

Tags: java, android

I am doing a time table project for my college, in which I want to generate notification on each hour using AlarmManager, I almost got the solution, but the alarm gets triggered during random time, like between hours. What I want is to trigger alarm manger messages on exactly each hour, like 7.00am,8.00am, and so on on everyday. My code is given below.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper2 db = new DatabaseHelper2(this);

private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private AlarmManager alarmManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Cursor resService = db.getAllData();
    int pref = 0;
    if(resService.getCount()!=0){

        Date date2 = new Date();
        int h=date2.getHours();
        int m = date2.getMinutes();
        int s = date2.getSeconds();

        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,alarmIntent,0);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        //int interval = 60 * 60 * 10000;
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR,pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this,"Alarm set at "+h+" : "+m+" : "+s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

**AlarmReciever.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Date d = new Date();
        Toast.makeText(context,"Broadcast message triggered at "+d.getHours()+":"+d.getMinutes()+":"+d.getSeconds() ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(service1);
    }
}
```

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    DatabaseHelper2 db = new DatabaseHelper2(this);
    String sub;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Date date = new Date();
        int now=date.getHours();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
        String dayOfWeek = sdf.format(date);
        Cursor resNow = db.getNowSub(now,dayOfWeek);

        if(resNow.getCount()!=0){
            if(resNow.moveToNext()){
                sub = resNow.getString(3);
            }
            NotificationManager notif = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Notification notify =  new Notification.Builder
                    (getApplicationContext()).setContentTitle("NowSub").setContentText("Now:"+sub+ " at "+date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes()+":"+date.getSeconds()).setContentTitle("currenet subject").setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).build();
            notify.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notif.notify(0, notify);

        }



        return START_STICKY;

    }
```

I spent more than a week for this particular problem, hope someone will help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR,pendingIntent);
```

You need to pass an actual time when you want this to wake up, not `System.currentTimeMillis()`

So something like

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date newDate = calendar.setTime(date2);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR,pendingIntent);
```

Try this instead. I change to `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME`

Comment: I tried this, but this is not being executed on exactly each hour.

Comment: Sorry for being late, this code worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As in the description of AlarmManager:

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS
>   will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There
>   are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery
>   guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and
>   setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose
>   targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the
>   previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when
>   requested.

I suggest to use `setExact` instead of `setRepeating` to be waked up at an exact time.

Also, check out `JobScheduler` as stated here: [Android AlarmManager setExact() is not exact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38094420/android-alarmmanager-setexact-is-not-exact)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I want to repeat the alarm everyday on each hour, I think the setExact method will trigger only once.

Comment: Probably JobScheduler can make a repeating trigger.