# Sending notification via AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver does not work?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-alarms, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm scheduling a notification for 5 days ahead, so I create an alarm using the AlarmManager who fires a PendingIntent which triggers my BroadcastReceiver.

If I try the code for 10 seconds, it works. When I try it for 5 days, nothing happens.

The class `NotificationScheduler` is a helper class for setting and updating alarms.

The fire-dates are correct since I store them in a database, and I already proofed it.

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".reminder.ReminderReceiver" />
```

NotificationScheduler:

```
class NotificationScheduler {

    companion object {

        const val NOTIFICATION_EXTRA_CLAIM_ID = "notification_extra_bookentry_id"

        const val INTENT_ACTION_REMINDER = "at.guger.moneybook.reminder"

        fun setReminder(context: Context, bookEntryId: Long, fireDate: Date? = null) {
            val mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()

            val lFireDate = if (fireDate == null) {
                mCalendar.timeInMillis += 5 * 24 * 3600 * 1000
                mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12)

                mCalendar.time
            } else {
                fireDate
            }

            create(context, bookEntryId, lFireDate.time)

            AppDatabase.getInstance(context).reminderDao().insert(Reminder(bookEntryId, lFireDate))
        }

        fun updateReminder(context: Context, bookEntryId: Long) {
            cancel(context, bookEntryId)

            val mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            mCalendar.timeInMillis += 5 * 24 * 3600 * 1000
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12)

            create(context, bookEntryId, mCalendar.timeInMillis)

            AppDatabase.getInstance(context).reminderDao().update(Reminder(bookEntryId, mCalendar.time))
        }

        fun cancelReminder(context: Context, bookEntryId: Long) {
            cancel(context, bookEntryId)

            AppDatabase.getInstance(context).reminderDao().delete(Reminder(bookEntryId))
        }

        private fun create(context: Context, bookEntryId: Long, fireDate: Long) {
            val mAlarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

            val mComponentName = ComponentName(context, ReminderReceiver::class.java)
            context.packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(mComponentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)

            val mIntent = Intent(context, ReminderReceiver::class.java)
            mIntent.action = INTENT_ACTION_REMINDER
            mIntent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_EXTRA_CLAIM_ID, bookEntryId)

            val mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, bookEntryId.toInt(), mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

            if (Utils.isKitKat()) {
                mAlarmManager.setWindow(AlarmManager.RTC, fireDate, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR, mPendingIntent)
            } else {
                mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, fireDate, mPendingIntent)
            }
        }

        private fun cancel(context: Context, bookEntryId: Long) {
            val mAlarmManager: AlarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

            val mComponentName = ComponentName(context, ReminderReceiver::class.java)
            context.packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(mComponentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)

            val mIntent = Intent(context, ReminderReceiver::class.java)
            mIntent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_EXTRA_CLAIM_ID, bookEntryId)

            val mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, bookEntryId.toInt(), mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

            mAlarmManager.cancel(mPendingIntent)
            mPendingIntent.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
class ReminderReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (context != null && intent != null) {
            when (intent.action) {
                NotificationScheduler.INTENT_ACTION_REMINDER -> {
                    val mPowerManager = context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
                    val mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, this::class.simpleName)

                    mWakeLock.acquire(WAKELOCK_TIME)

                    val iClaimEntryId = intent.getLongExtra(NotificationScheduler.NOTIFICATION_EXTRA_CLAIM_ID, -1)

                    showNotification(context, iClaimEntryId)
                    AppDatabase.getInstance(context).reminderDao().delete(Reminder(iClaimEntryId))

                    mWakeLock.release()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun showNotification(context: Context, claimEntryId: Long) {
        val mNotificationManager: NotificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        val nBuilder: Notification.Builder

        if (Utils.isOreo()) {
            val mNotificationChannel = NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATIONCHANNEL_CLAIMREMINDERID, context.getString(R.string.notificationchannel_claimreminder_title), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
            mNotificationChannel.description = context.getString(R.string.notificationchannel_claimreminder_description)

            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mNotificationChannel)

            nBuilder = Notification.Builder(context, NOTIFICATIONCHANNEL_CLAIMREMINDERID)
        } else {
            nBuilder = Notification.Builder(context)
        }

        val mClaimEntry: BookEntry = AppDatabase.getInstance(context).bookEntryDao().get(claimEntryId)

        val mCurrencyFormatter = DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Preferences.getInstance(context).currency.locale)

        nBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_money)
        nBuilder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notification_claimreminder_title, mCurrencyFormatter.format(mClaimEntry.dValue)))
        val sContacts = mClaimEntry.getContacts(context).joinToString().takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }
                ?: "-"
        nBuilder.setContentText(context.getString(R.string.notification_claimreminder_content, sContacts))
        nBuilder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
        nBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)

        mNotificationManager.notify(mClaimEntry.lId!!.toInt(), nBuilder.build())
    }

    companion object {
        const val NOTIFICATIONCHANNEL_CLAIMREMINDERID = "notification_channel_claimreminder"

        const val WAKELOCK_TIME: Long = 1000
    }
}
```

Comment: When you tried it for 5 days, did you reboot the device in between? AlarmManager scheduling is lost after a device reboot. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034357/does-alarm-manager-persist-even-after-reboot

Comment: @kphil I did not reboot the device

Comment: Have you tried the 10 seconds period while your app is in foreground or in recent tasks? I assume for 5 days it wasn't. Do you get the notification after 10 seconds when your app is **not** in foreground / recent tasks? 
Another thought, just to be sure. You are not calling `updateReminder` in between for 5 days period?

Comment: @kphil Just tried it, it works with 10 secs when the app is closed..
I'm sure `updateReminder` isn't called because I did not open the app in those five days. And if, the fire date would be changed but the fire date was correct!

Comment: Are you targeting sdk 23 or higher? Than doze mode would also come into picture. The 10 seconds wait despite app being closed might not be enough to trigger doze mode. During doze mode wake locks would be ignored. Maybe you can verify that by using a lower api or making sure doze mode is on or off. 
You can read here for more information https://en.proft.me/2017/05/7/scheduling-operations-alarmmanager-android/ . There's also an adb command for listing all pending alarms, to help with debugging.

Comment: I'm targeting sdk 27, how do I ensure my pendingintent is fired in doze mode?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179134/discussion-between-the-dani-and-kphil).

Comment: What device are you testing it? This has some significance with the issue

Comment: Galaxy S7 running Android 8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38302891/5130239 - try other methods of alarm or use job scheduler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had issues with AlarmManager, so I am using WorkManager now.

[WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager) was introduced with Android Jetpack / Architecture Components.

#### Solution

- First add dependency for WorkManager, you can find latest versions [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components#workmanager).
- Create a **`Worker class`**, and code for showing notification in **`doWork()`**.
- Schedule this work on your app start, also check if already not scheduled. I already created a method named `isWorkScheduled()` in below class for ease.
- You can send additional data to your task (like putExtra()) by [setInputData()](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced).
- Schedule your one time task in first activity onCreate() or Application class onCreate.

Example

```
public static final String TAG_WORK = "myTag";
if(!MyWork.isWorkScheduled(TAG_WORK))
    MyWork.scheduleOneTimeTask(TAG_WORK, 5, TimeUnit.DAYS)
```

#### `MyWork.java`

```
public class MyWork extends Worker {
    public static void scheduleOneTimeTask(String tag, long duration, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        OneTimeWorkRequest compressionWork =
                new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWork.class).setInitialDelay(duration, timeUnit).addTag(tag)
                        .build();
        WorkManager instance = WorkManager.getInstance();
        if (instance != null) {
            instance.enqueue(compressionWork);
        }
    }

    private boolean isWorkScheduled(String tag) {
        WorkManager instance = WorkManager.getInstance();
        if (instance == null) return false;
        LiveData<List<WorkStatus>> statuses = instance.getStatusesByTag(tag);
        if (statuses.getValue() == null) return false;
        boolean running = false;
        for (WorkStatus workStatus : statuses.getValue()) {
            running = workStatus.getState() == State.RUNNING | workStatus.getState() == State.ENQUEUED;
        }
        return running;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        // show notification
        return Result.SUCCESS;
        // (Returning RETRY tells WorkManager to try this task again
        // later; FAILURE says not to try again.)
    }
}
```

> I suggested you WorkManger only, because I created a sample earlier
>   days with **[JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler)**, **[EvernoteJobs](https://github.com/evernote/android-job)**,
>   **[AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager)**, **[JobService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService)**, and **[WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager)**. In which I started periodic task of 15 minutes with each of these. and
>   wrote logs of each in separate file when invoked.
>
> Conclusion of this test was that. **[WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager)** and **[EvernoteJobs](https://github.com/evernote/android-job)** were
>   most efficient to do jobs. Now because EvernoteJobs will use
>   WorkManager from next version. So I came up with WorkManager.

#### Update

Minimum time for scheduling periodic task is 15 minutes so please keep in mind. You can read more in [documentation.](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest#MIN_PERIODIC_FLEX_MILLIS)

Comment: Does WorkManager execute during device idle?

Comment: Usually it runs, it only pause only in doze mode (which pause every other task too.)

Comment: But it should be resumed when doze mode ends?

Comment: I tried, too but it didn't work.. How fast will WorkManager recognise and start after doze mode exits?

Comment: I created a sample writing logs with task. And I found all time logs in oreo. Just I did not get some durations logs, perhaps that was doze mode.

Comment: I am not aware of how much time it takes to reschedule task. But I am sure it is trustworthy than any one else.

Comment: Then go ahead, it will work fine.  Test it for 1 day. If you find 1 day test fine, then it will be same in case of 5 days too. Because oreo device goes many times in doze mode in a day.

Comment: On my emulator i can force doze mode via adb shell .. If it works there for e.g. 15 mins, it should work for 5 days too, right?

Comment: Yes obviously bro

Comment: But it doesnt work in many devices, e.g. in Xiaomi devices.

Answer (score 0):

Is the device ever shut down during the five-day period? According to the documentation:

> By default, all alarms are canceled when a device shuts down. To prevent this from happening, you can design your application to automatically restart a repeating alarm if the user reboots the device. This ensures that the AlarmManager will continue doing its task without the user needing to manually restart the alarm.
>   [Set an alarm when the device restarts.](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#boot)

Another thing that comes to mind is you may want to use `AlarmManager.RCT_WAKEUP` instead of `AlarmManager.RTC` to make sure the device is awake to deliver the intent and create and dispatch your notification.

Try:

```
if (Utils.isKitKat()) {
    mAlarmManager.setWindow(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, fireDate, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR, mPendingIntent)
} else {
    mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, fireDate, mPendingIntent)
}
```

Comment: I didn't shutdown or reboot the device in the period! Will RTC_WAKEUP also wake up the screen of the phone?

Comment: No, it just grants you a short time in which to run some code. I think it's 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably , it is the case when your device is going in Doze mode and Alarm manager is not triggering your scheduled alarm 
Try using( this is Java code ):

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, fireDate, pendingIntent);
    }
    else{
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, fireDate, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
```

Take a look at [setExactAndAllowWhileIdle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))