# Android alarm manager fire at the exact moment

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, alarm

I have an app which needs to do task at the exact time provided just like the stock android alarm clock I have used **setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()** / **setExact()**. But BroadcastReciever fires after some minutes and sometimes after opening the app, is there any workaround for it?

Alarm Setter code

```
// set Alarm
Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, AlarmReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("alarmInfo", extraInfo);
intent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 123456, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {             
   alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, finalTime - 400, pendingIntent);
} else {
   alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, finalTime - 400, pendingIntent);
}
```

BroadcastReciever

```
setNextAlarm();
Log.d("RESULT", "fired");
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmSoundService.class);
//        Log.d("extra", "alarmInfo: " + intent.getStringExtra("alarmInfo"));
alarmIntent.putExtra("alarmInfo", intent.getStringExtra("alarmInfo"));
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    context.startForegroundService(alarmIntent);
} else {
    context.startService(alarmIntent);
}
```

**setNextAlarm()** is the previous code I provided which sets the alarm for the future task.

### EDIT

Ok so I have solved my problem the first is getting my alarm to fire at the exact moment so setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() / setExact() are both kind of exact so if I need to show user something and have to be accurate 
I used the [setAlarmClock()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) as the android doc explains

> The system may also do some prep-work when it sees that such an alarm
>   coming    up, to reduce the amount of background work that could
>   happen if this causes the device to fully wake up

The second problem was that the alarm wasn't firing up unless I open the app this was due to the fact that two alarms were firing between the interval of 5 minutes and since I was using [setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))
and the android doc explains

> Under normal system operation, it will not dispatch these alarms more
>   than about every minute (at which point every such pending alarm is
>   dispatched); when in low-power idle modes this duration may be
>   significantly longer, such as 15 minutes.

And that was it.

Comment: Well, there are issues for which the receiver fires after somw time, maybe a minute or two. You can try reading answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38094420/8192914)

Comment: However, I didn't encounter problems where the receiver fires after opening the app. It would be helpful to understand the reason if you provide relavent codes.

Comment: @ganjaam I have edited with the code please take a look

Comment: Remove the call to setExact.  It may be overriding the setExactAndAllowWhileIdle, since both go to the same pending intent.  You only need one of those two.

Comment: @GabeSechan but the if condition will not ensure just that??

Comment: My appologies I missed the if for some reason yesterday.  I edited the spacing in your code to make it more clear.